# Java GUI Jpanel not fitting to contents

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel

Can anyone help  me display my GUI correctly? at the moment when I make a new instance the GUI appears as a small box and does not fit the contents at all.

The way in which I make the interface is by calling the makeFrame Method:

```
    private void makeFrame()
    {
    frame = new JFrame("game");

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPane.add(menubar, BorderLayout.NORTH);


    JPanel gamePanel1 = new JPanel();


  buttons = new JButton[boardsize][boardsize];
    mineBoard = new int[9][9];
    for (int a = 0; a < boardsize; a++) 
        for (int b = 0; b < boardsize; b++) {
            buttons[a][b] = new JButton("");
           contentPane.add(buttons[a][b]);
            buttons[a][b].setBounds(30+gridsize*a,30+gridsize*b,gridsize,gridsize);
            buttons[a][b].addMouseListener(new MouseListener(a,b));
            setx(a);
            sety(b);
            settried(false);
            setmine(false);
    }



    assignmines();


   updateGamesPlayed() ;
   UpdateName();
   contentPane.add(gamePanel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);



   Box gamePanel = Box.createVerticalBox();
   add(gamePanel);

    gamePanel.add(nameEnter);
    gamePanel.add(saveName);
    gamePanel.add(namelabel);
    gamePanel.add(scorelabel);
    gamePanel.add(gamesPlayed);
    gamePanel.add(gamesWon);
    gamePanel.add(status);
    gamePanel.add(noMines);
    contentPane.add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    contentPane.add(status, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    makeMenuBar();
}
```

How can i get the Jpanels to fit around the contents?

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
frame . setSize ( height , width ) ;
```

or:

```
frame . setPreferredSize ( dimension ) ;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, perhaps something is overriding it?